# Entity Framework Core - Creating a model from an existing database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Stumbled on the moment of creation of the entities which are stored in one table.

There is a table Elements. It contains a list of products.
There is a Variants table - it contains data with a list of production operations necessary for the manufacture of products. All operations in this table are associated with a variant number.

I want to make a property of type list, which will contain a list of options, and already each option should contain a list of operations.

Model Element

```cs
public partial class Element
{
    [Key]
    public int ElementID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Variant

```cs
public partial class Variant
{
    [Key]
    public int StepID { get; set; }

    public byte VariantNum { get; set; }

    public byte? Step { get; set; }

    public int ELID { get; set; }

    public short work_code { get; set; }

    public short WorkPlaceID { get; set; }

    public int RoutingID { get; set; }

    public bool? IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

[This is what a table looks like in sql management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TyAm.png)

In c# I'm just learning, entity framework core is also in the process of learning

What have I done so far

```cs
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<byte> NambersOfVariant {
    get {
        List<byte> Result = new List<byte>();
        var r = Variants.OrderBy(s => s.IsDefault).OrderBy(s=>s.VariantNum).GroupBy(p => p.VariantNum).Select(g => (byte)g.Key);
        foreach (var n in r) {
            Result.Add(n);
        }
        return Result;
    }
}

[NotMapped]
public List<List<Variant>> Steps
{
    get {
        List<List<Variant>> Result = new List<List<Variant>>();
        var group = Variants.GroupBy(p => p.Step);
        foreach (var n in group)
        {
            List<Variant> List1 = new List<Variant>();

            foreach (var v in n) {
                List1.Add(v);    
            }
            Result.Add(List1);
        }
        return Result;
    }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Element>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Variants)
        .WithOne(s => s.EL)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ELID);
}
```

But this is not at all what I would like to have.

Most likely it is necessary to use "owns many", but I don't understand how to do it yet

Comment: have you considered using EF database first approach to generate your db models from existing database schema?

Comment: Of course. But the database itself was made by other software a very long time ago and not entirely correct - the tables do not indicate the links.
The created models are obtained completely without any connections.

Comment: I don't see any lists in Element table, is that a full tables data ? Or you have to get the list form Product table by ids ?

Comment: @DarkkL, There are no problems with displaying a list of products. The task is to make a navigation property (Collection) for the product that contains a list of possible options (the VariantNum column in the Variant table), and inside each of this property to have a list of steps (the remaining columns of the Variant table with selection by the current VariantNum)